# How to capture high-resolution google map image?

Tags: image, google-maps, google-chrome, resolution, capture

Recently I built a website called [Google Map Customizer](http://www.chengfolio.com/googlemap.html), which lets you customize the colors on a Google Map and get large, high resolution images. But the problem is now I have to use third-party tool to capture the image. I am wondering if it is possible to do so by using some native codes? (Java maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

check it on here [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index)

Comment: Note that static maps API does _not_ offer high res images unless you pay for it. See more here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Imagesizes